# Proving interiorality and exteriorality of curves using the Jordan curve lemma

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

[image: page1]

How do I formally go about proving (i), (ii) and (iii)?
Can I get a formal proof for all three parts(I am new to topology). This is what I have for part(i) - γ1 divides C into interior, exterior and boundary of γ1.Since the image of γ2 is disjoint from γ1, γ2 should lie in the interior of γ1 or its exterior. Is this adequate?

For part (ii) I have sketch of proof - its not formal and it is derived from pictorial intuition. Again I would appreciate a formal proof. This is what I have: γ2∩ext(γ2)=∅. C is divided into int, ext and boundary of γ1, therefore since γ1 and γ2 have disjoint boundaries, int(γ1⊆int(γ2) and ext(γ1)⊃ext(γ2)

For part(iii) I do not have even geometric intuition

Can I please get some help?

Comment: Did you try to apply the Jordan curve theorem as the final hint told you to do so? According to this theorem, the curves delimit exactly two connected domains of the complex plane. One of them is bounded and we name it the interior of the curve and the other one is the exterior of the curve. If $\gamma_2$ meets the interior and the exterior of $\gamma_2$ then $\gamma_1$ has to meet $\gamma_2$, which gives the answer to the first question.

Comment: I have some idea of the first question @halbaroth. If $\gamma_1$ divides $C$ into an interior and exterior, then a second curve which is disjoint in its image from $\gamma_1$ will have to reside either in the exterior of $\gamma_1$ or in its interior. It seems intuitive for the first question. How do we formalize this into a proof. And also how to approach part 2 and 3

Comment: The curve $\gamma_2$ is **connected**. Hence, if $\gamma_2$ meets the interior and the exterior of $\gamma_1$, then it meets $\gamma_1$ as well.

Comment: @halbaroth, Can I get a formal proof for all three parts(I am new to topology). This is what I have for part(i) - $\gamma_1$ divides $C$ into interior, exterior and boundary of $\gamma_1$.Since the image of $\gamma_2$ is disjoint from $\gamma_1$, $\gamma_2$ should lie in the interior of $\gamma_1$ or its exterior. Is this adequate?

Comment: For part (ii) I have sketch of proof - its not formal and it is derived from pictorial intuition. Again I would appreciate a formal proof. This is what I have: $\gamma_2 \cap ext(\gamma_2) = \emptyset$. $C$ is divided into int, ext and boundary of $\gamma_1$, therefore since $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ have disjoint boundaries, int($\gamma_1  \subseteq int(\gamma_2)$ and $ext(\gamma_1) \supset ext(\gamma_1)$.

Comment: For part(iii)  i do not even have geometric intuition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will need the following facts: 0) image of a Jordan curve $\gamma$ is compact, hence closed, and $int(\gamma)$ and $ext(\gamma)$ are open; 1) for open sets, connected is the same as path connected; 2) for a Jourdan curve $\gamma$ any two points joined by a path $\beta$ disjoint from $\gamma$ are either both in $int(\gamma)$ or are both in $ext(\gamma)$ (the intersection of $\beta$ with either of these is clopen in $\beta$, so is either empty or the  whole thing).

Thus, by 1), $ext(\gamma)$ is precisely the set of points in the plane connected by a path "to infinity" (i.e. there exists a large ball such that for any point $P$ in a complement of this ball, $ext(\gamma)$ is precisely the set of points  $p$ such that there exists a path from  $p$ to $P$ avoiding $\gamma$).

Now first part of the exercise is obvious: any two points of $\gamma_2$ are connected by a path avoiding $\gamma_1$, namely a piece of $\gamma_2$, so by property 2) lie either both in $int(\gamma_1)$ or both in $ext(\gamma_1)$.

For the second part of the exercise, assume that $p$ is in the exterior of $\gamma_1$. Then it can be connected to infinity by a path $\beta$ in exterior of $\gamma_1$ (i.e. to a point $P$ sufficiently far to be in exterior of both $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$). Since $\gamma_2$ avoids the exterior of $\gamma_1$, $\beta$ is either fully in interior or fully in exterior of $\gamma_2$; but it has endpoint $P$ in the exterior, so it is fully in the exterior. Thus $p$ is also in the  exterior of $\gamma_2$, and $ext(\gamma_1)\subseteq ext(\gamma_2)$, as wanted. Now for the other part, suppose $q$ is in the interior of $\gamma_2$. We want to show its in the interior of $\gamma_1$. Well, $q$ has a ball around it all in the interior of $\gamma_2$, thus disjoint from the exterior of $\gamma_2$, and  by what we have just proved this ball is disjoint from the exterior of $\gamma_1$. Since $\gamma_1$ is the boundary of its exterior, this is only possible for points on the interior of $\gamma_1$. So $int(\gamma_2)\subseteq\int(\gamma_1)$, as wanted.

For the third part, we first prove that for any Jordan curve $\gamma$ and any point $p$ in $int(\gamma)$ there exists a path $\beta$ from $p$ to a point $b \in \gamma$ which avoids $ext(\gamma)$. Indeed, pick $q\in ext(\gamma)$ and connect $p$ to $q$ by a path (say, a straight segment $
\beta(t)=tp+(1-t)q$), and take $b$ to be the first time this path hits $\gamma$ (i.e. $b=\beta(T)$ where $T=\inf \{t| \beta_t \notin int(\gamma)\}$). Then the part of this path up to that point is as we want ($b=\beta(T)$ is in closure of $int(\gamma)$ and in closure of $ext(\gamma)\cap \gamma$, so is in $\gamma$, and all $t<T$ have $\beta(t)\in int(\gamma)$).
Now the exercise is easy: given $p\in int(\gamma_1)$ connect it to $b\in \gamma_1$ by a path in $int(\gamma_1)$, and thus avoiding $\gamma_2$. Now $b\in \gamma_1 \subset ext(\gamma_2)$, so by property 2, $p$ is also in $ext(\gamma_2)$.